# How to generalize html element creation from JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

So I'm making a c++ program that generates a HTML web page.
And in it, I generate the body and also the script (javascript) using jquery.

My question is, using the same code how can I create either a checkbox input element and a jquery ui slider?
I explain myself:
To create an element I have a function like:

```
CreateElement(char * element_type, char * element_id, char * tag);
```

And to generate the body of the element:

```
GenerateHtml()
{
    output_stream << "<" << tag << " type='" << element_type << "' id='" << element_id << "'></" << tag <<">";
}
```

and for the script:

```
GenerateJavaScript()
{
    ...
    output_stream << "$('#" << element_id << "')." << element_type << "();";
    ...
}
```

So if I do:

```
CreateElement("spinner","my_spinner","input");
```

I will have the following html:

```
<body>
...
<input type='spinner' id='my_spinner'></input>
...

<script>
    ...
    $('#my_spinner').spinner();
    ...
</script>
</body>
```

And I see on the web page exactly what I want, but the problem happends when I want to create a none jquery UI element like a checkbox or a range.
Cause the script will be:

```
$('#my_checkbox').checkbox();
$('#my_range').range();
```

And this is not working.
Is there a way to create both of them with the same javascript/jquery function?

Comment: There is no `checkbox` or `range` jquery functions, so this is not the way... not that using c++ to create jQuery code is my best idea of writing HTML page...

Comment: Thanks, you are right there is no such functions in jquery and I know it.
But what is the way then?

Comment: You can write your own little function that takes tag name and additional attribute-value pairs as parameters (an object would do best for passing the attributes), build the HTML string from that, and then just passes it to `$(html_code_here)` to create the element.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid this was the only solution, since I would like the end user not to enter any html code, but just call functions.Thank you for your answer.